# Angular ui-grid export to CSV callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid in Angular 1.5 and I need to track the export to .csv event, so I can know when a user clicks on this option. There are any callback of this function or something like that? 
I tried the documentation with no success.

Comment: You have your code and the documentation, and all we have is a broad description of your issue. Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define export callbacks. While defining report grid options, you can use `exporterFieldCallback`.

Post your elaborated query, so that we can give proper solution.